# How should I filter a JSON using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, associative-array

how can I filter this JSON by the array of areas, within that array? I need to display in my html only the items that have a certain area. In the case below, I must display only the `area_one`

```
[
   {
      "ID":789,
      "title":"Title Page",
      "image_desktop":"image21.jpg",
      "image_mobile":"image234.jpg",
      "link":"#",
      "areas":[
         "area_one"
      ]
   },
   {
      "ID":789,
      "title":"Title Page three",
      "image_desktop":"image21.jpg",
      "image_mobile":"image234.jpg",
      "link":"#",
      "areas":[
         "area_one"
      ]
   },
   {
      "ID":765,
      "title":"Title Page 2",
      "image_desktop":"image231.jpg",
      "image_mobile":"image421.jpg",
      "link":"#\/link",
      "areas":[
         "area_two"
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: + [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: Of note, you never "filter JSON". You filter an array and JSON is just one of the ways to represent it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for outer array and [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for the inner one:

```js
let input = [
   {
      "ID":789,
      "title":"Title Page",
      "image_desktop":"image21.jpg",
      "image_mobile":"image234.jpg",
      "link":"#",
      "areas":[
         "area_one"
      ]
   },
   {
      "ID":789,
      "title":"Title Page three",
      "image_desktop":"image21.jpg",
      "image_mobile":"image234.jpg",
      "link":"#",
      "areas":[
         "area_one"
      ]
   },
   {
      "ID":765,
      "title":"Title Page 2",
      "image_desktop":"image231.jpg",
      "image_mobile":"image421.jpg",
      "link":"#\/link",
      "areas":[
         "area_two"
      ]
   }
];

let result = input.filter(x => x.areas.some(area => area === "area_one"));
console.log(result);
```